# how to solve Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement;

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-multidex

This is our Build gradle Module:APP
  how to solve  Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement problem please give me some solution    all the dependcies are given below  so  there is play-services  and google-services as well so give me solution for

```
repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId 
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled = true
        }
        dexOptions {
            jumboMode = true
            preDexLibraries = false
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
        configurations{
            all*.exclude module:'gson'  //Remove duplicate dependencies： gson
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile project(':lib')
        compile project(':tablayoutsupport')
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
        compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.7'
        compile 'com.anthonycr.grant:permissions:1.0'
        compile 'com.auron:permission-manage:1.1.6'
        compile 'com.github.andyxialm:ColorDialog:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
        compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'){
            force = true;
        }
        compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'){
            force = true;
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }

        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4') {
            force = true;
        }
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
        compile ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'){
            force=true;
        }
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

and this is build.gradle (project)
        so tell me what is solution of this eror    how i install it sucessfully
    Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    and this    build.gradle and app is not running so what is the solutions

```
 buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
            }
            maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.51"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
            }
        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: What's the actual error? Can you please share the logs? Also, never share your package name and related things on the portal it should be confidential.

Comment: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement     this is eror